# Expectation of Indicatior with Bivariate Normal

Tags: expected-value, bivariate-distributions

Let (X,Y) be bivariate normal with correlation $\rho$.
I am asked to calculate:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^X \mathbb{I}_{X\leq Y}]
\end{align*}
I have tried plugging in the pdf but it's a mess. any hints?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried writing it as a double integral and form squares for y first, do substitution by variables so I end up only with an integral over x. but then I end up with x inside the cdf of the normal distribution